# Javascript - using apply to call a bound function

Tags: javascript

Say we have the following sample Javascript code:

```
var modeller = "foo";
var provider1 = function (modeller, content, optionalArg) {
    alert("this: " + this + ", content: " + content + ", optionalArg: " + optionalArg);
}.bind(null, modeller);

var provider2 = function (content, optionalArg) {
    alert("this: " + this + ", content: " + content + ", optionalArg: " + optionalArg);
};

var createConsumer = function () {
    // some arbitrary private vars
    var content = 1; 
    var option = 2; 

    var doConsume = function(provider) {
        provider.apply(this, [content, option])
    };
    return {consume: doConsume};
};

// Now use them
var consumer = createConsumer();

consumer.consume(provider1);
consumer.consume(provider2);
```

This is simplified a lot for demo purposes, but the gist is that `provider1` is already bound, and `provider2` is not - the consumer cannot pass itself as the `this` argument for `provider1`.

**The questions:** Is there a way to detect this kind of case where a function is already bound? Is there a way to get `provider1` to use the consumer as `this`?  Assuming the answer is no, what is the best way to work around this sort of situation?

Comment: No, it is not. It's even quite impossible "to work around that" - but why would you want to at all? Whoever bound `provider1` to a specific object did that for a good reason

Comment: Addition: It's "quite impossible" because `bind` (built-in or common library implementations) does/do not expose the original function-object but always proxy it. The original function object is caught in the local (and private) binding scope of the resulting proxy-function. It is possible to imagine/create some `bindWithTricks` to do this; but again, non-standard/not-common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Is there a way to detect this kind of case where a function is already bound?"*

No.

> *"Is there a way to get `provider1` to use the `consumer` as `this`?"*

No.

> *"...what is the best way to work around this sort of situation?"*

Since it seems like you want to bind an argument but not the `this` value, I would make an argument binder method on `Function.prototype` that returns a function with only the arguments bound, and not `this`.

```
Function.prototype.argBind = function() {
    var _slicer = [].slice,
        orig_args = _slicer.call(arguments),
        orig_func = this;
    return function() {
        return orig_func.apply(this, orig_args.concat(_slicer.call(arguments)));
    };
};
```

---

Then you'd use it like this:

```
var modeller = "foo";
var provider1 = function (modeller, content, optionalArg) {
    alert("this: " + this + ", content: " + content + ", optionalArg: " + optionalArg);
}.argBind(modeller);
```

Now the `provider1` function will be invoked with whatever normal `this` value is given, but the `modeller` will be bound as the first argument.

Comment: I suspected as much for the first two parts.  I was hoping there was something built in already that does something like that argBind function, which matches up quite well with what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, nothing built it, but easy enough to create. :-)

Comment: "Is there a way to detect this kind of case where a function is already bound?": Yes: const isBound = !func.hasOwnProperty('prototype');

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to detect if a function is already bound but it's not really elegant:

`/\[native code]/.test(foo.toString());`

Bound functions have native code as toString(). This works for Chrome(NodeJS). I don't know about other browsers.

Comment: This would seem to be the correct answer for the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code which demonstrates that 1st argument of apply() and call() do not change the value of 'this' inside a bound function:

```
let bf = f .bind  (123);
let n  = bf.call  (234);
let n2 = bf.apply (234);
ok (n  === 123);
ok (n2 === 123);

function f ()
{ return this;
}
```

( ok() above is a function that  throws an error if called with argument that is not truthy).

**Can you detect whether a function is bound or not?.**

The answer of Mihai Voicescu above seems correct in my view. A variation of that would be:

Place some  unique string (like say your name as the author of the function) into a comment in the source-code of the function you later will want to test for "bindness". Take the toString() of the function being tested. If that does not include the unique string it does in your original source then you know it is a bound.  Best to test for the browsers you want to support, as always.

**What is the best way to work around this situation?**

Use an ordinary optional argument to pass in the object you want to use as the "substitute-this". Call it 'self' for instance. The 'self' argument can declare its default value to be 'this'. Then inside the function use 'self' everywhere instead of 'this'. By default its value will be the same as the bound 'this', but you can alter that by passing in an explicit different value for the optional argument 'self'.  If you do want to use the bound 'this' you don't need to pass in the optional self-argument at all.